# Spring AOP: Performing Validations

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am performing some validations in the Aspect having this code:

```
public void beforeMethodExecJoinPoint(JoinPoint jp){
    System.out.println("Invoking Method: " + jp.toString());
    System.out.println("Args passed: " + Arrays.toString(jp.getArgs()));
    if(Arrays.toString(jp.getArgs()).contains("XXX")){
        System.out.println("True"); // Need to replace this
    }
}
```

If the validation fails, then I don't want to invoke the calling method and would like to return from the advice itself. I am not sure how to perform this. Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an around advice. Of the ProceedingJoinPoint argument to the method, don't invoke the proceed() method if you don't want the target method to run but instead return something you like. Here's some different piece of code for your understanding:

```
   public Object methodExecutionMonitor(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

       long startTime = System.nanoTime();
       Object retVal = pjp.proceed();
       long endTime = System.nanoTime();

       System.out.println("Method execution time (ns): " + pjp.getSignature() + " "
               + (endTime - startTime));

       return retVal;
   }
```

Comment: In this case, returning something everytime becomes mandatory right? What if I dont want to return anything?

Comment: Returning or not depends on the target method return type. So even returning null should work.

Answer (score 1):

Using before advice, this is not possible without changing a lot of the Spring AOP infrastructure.

Currently, it is implemented with a `MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor` which invokes the before advice and then proceeds with the advised method's invocation. The code is

```
public Object invoke(MethodInvocation mi) throws Throwable {
    this.advice.before(mi.getMethod(), mi.getArguments(), mi.getThis() );
    return mi.proceed();
}
```

So the only way to terminate execution would be to throw an Exception. You probably don't want that.

Do what Kamal is suggesting and use an around advice.

Answer (score 1):

First, your before advice could throw a runtime exception that could eventually be catched by caller. And if the usage of exception is not an option, you will have to use an around advice.